# Extracting yyyy/MM/dd formated date from datetime datatype in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, view

I have my date values in postdate column in articles table in  sql database table. It stores all date as well as time. I would like to get the date part only. i.e from 2010/07/01 12:45:12 i would likfe to get 2010/07/01
in my view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008, you can cast the value as DATE. With previous versions, you can use a trick over DATEADD:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME;

SELECT @d = '2010-07-22 12:45:22';

-- all versions of sql server
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @d), 0);
-- sql server 2008
SELECT CAST(@d AS DATE);
```

Greets
Flo

Comment: amazing, I never knew about that DATEADD trick before! I was always converting to/from a char(10) to 'fake it'.

Comment: Thanks :-)! I've learned that on SCC. Since then, I've already used it hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

you can use either of the two

```
select substring(getdate(),0,10)
```

use

```
 select convert(varchar,getdate(),111)
```

[see this for more formats](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1145)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)
```

[How to format datetime & date in Sql Server 2005](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)